Django is not raising validationerror
class confirm_password_form(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm_Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
    
    def clean(self):
        print("this is clean")
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data["confirm_password"]
        print("in clean password ",password)
        print("in clean confirm_password",confirm_password)
        if password!=confirm_password:
            print("this is not equal condition")
            raise forms.ValidationError("both password should be match")

In above code Django is not raising the validation error. It is printing 'this is not equal condition' but it is not raising error.
I have tried available solutions.

How do you run the clean method? By running form.is_valid()? Please share a proper [mre] that demonstrates your problem.

ValidationError should be imported from django.core.exceptions. link
ProTip:
Python recommends using secrets module's compare_digest function to compare passwords to avoid timing attack

secrets.compare_digest(a, b) return True if strings or bytes-like objects a and b are equal, otherwise False, using a “constant-time compare”

import secrets
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class confirm_password_form(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm_Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput,required=True)
    
    def clean(self):
        print("this is clean")
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data["confirm_password"]
        print("in clean password ",password)
        print("in clean confirm_password",confirm_password)
        if !secrets.compare_digest(password, confirm_password):
            print("this is not equal condition")
            raise ValidationError("both password should be match")


Uhh, that's probably not the problem. Also there isn't really any risk of a timing attack when comparing those two fields since both are plain text values coming from user input (This form is probably used while registering the users or something like a forgot password flow)...

i think Your code looks mostly correct, but there might be a small issue in how you're accessing the cleaned data.
try this:-
from django import forms

class ConfirmPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        
        if password and confirm_password and password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Both passwords should match")

